# Where does the phrase "that tracks" come from?

Tags: etymology

I'm wondering where "that tracks" comes from, i.e. meaning "that makes sense". I've done a bit of Googling and all I could find was a Reddit post with a bunch of different guesses that all seem plausible, but I was hoping to get a more certain answer.

Comment: `That tracks` is not a phrase I would use in that context. Possibly as a variation of `that follows` meaning one things follows on logically from something else already agreed.

Comment: @Aidan It is very informal way to say “that follows the path I would predict based on what I know”, which could be summarized as “that makes sense”.  I wouldn’t think there was enough context in n the question to say it would or wouldn’t be used in a particular context. There isn’t even a full sentence of context.